# i want to use following bintray maven artifact using Gradle in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

```
repositories 

    {
        maven {
            url  "http://androidluckyguys.bintray.com/AppBase" 
        }
    }
```

i am adding this to project build.gradle file , Android studio project is building without any error with this artifact , but i am not able to access any class from this artifact, kindly suggest what's wrong in my implementation.

here is my whole build.gradle

// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()

        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url  "http://androidluckyguys.bintray.com/AppBase"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Below is my Module level build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "org.csc.hajj"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.0.1'

    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    //compile project(':appbase')
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    //compile 'id.zelory:compressor:1.0.4'
    compile 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.3.+'

    compile 'com.roughike:bottom-bar:2.1.1'



}
```

Comment: I was having the same problem. I removed cached version of lib and restarted android studio.

Comment: You are not compiling anything from this project...? Show the rest of the Gradle file

Comment: Why did you put that in your `buildscript`? What are you trying to reference? Did you try putting instead within `allprojects { repositories {` ?

Comment: Post your module/build.gradle file